# Queries that do not select any table columns - do I understand this correctly?

Tags: mysql, optimization, select

I just read this article:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index

And at the bottom is this statement:

> Queries that do not select any table columns are often executed as index-only scan.
>
> Can you think of a meaningful example?

Problem is, there is no comments section, so I just want to verify, this is one example, correct?

```
SELECT 1 FROM `table_name` WHERE `indexed_column` = ?
```

This is to check whether a specified row exists.

So the questions:

- Are there any more practical uses for that?
- As a side note, I read somewhere that the above query might be more performant if encapsulated in `EXISTS`, I'm not sure how to check if it's true:

  ```
  SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `table_name` WHERE `indexed_column` = ? LIMIT 1)
  ```

  Is it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, possibly the canonical example would be `select count(*) from mytable` to get a row count.

That selects no data from the table and would most likely be satisfied by the primary key index, if available.

Comment: AFAIK this is instantanious on MyIsam tables, as this info is stored in table metadata, thus it's treated as a `const` query and does not even touch indices, a bit blurry on the details on InnoDb tables.

Comment: Yeah, that may work for a DB that doesn't support isolation levels (i.e., uncommitted transactions are invisible to others). It gets a bit trickier if you need that.